# pytest not skipping unmarked tests

Tags: python, pytest

We have a marked test that we expect to be not executed because py.test was invoked with another marker, yet the test is getting executed.

e.g.

```
@pytest.mark.stress
def test_one(some_fixture):
     pass

@pytest.mark.myplatform
def test_two(some_fixture):
     pass
```

If I run pytest with `--collectonly -m "myplatform and (not stress)`"  as an experiment, I see that I can work around the issue. I am assuming that using the fixture is in some way changing the way the markers are evaluated, but we assumed that using fixtures wouldn't effect the way tests are collected with markers. There is code in the fixture to look at the markers , but we don't change the pytest args in any way.
Chris

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. The `-m` option is correctly collecting each test for me with your above code and an empty `some_fixture` fixture. I am using Python 2.7.5 and pytest-2.5.2. Do you have any more information?

Comment: @user2249625 please try my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37583262/4988742 and let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `-k` flag instead and keep same filter logic "myplatform and not stress".

https://pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I updated the link in the answer: https://pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name

Answer (score 0):

The [marker based test selection/unselection](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#marking-test-functions-and-selecting-them-for-a-run) works to restrict the tests run to explicitly marked tests. You are just not able to recognize it if you use the `--collectonly` option (in examples below always `collected 3 items`).

Consider the test file `test_markers.py`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.stress
def test_stress():
     pass

@pytest.mark.myplatform
def test_myplatform():
     pass

def test_unmarked():
     pass
```

If you want to execute the "stress" tests only use (`-v` for verbose output)

```
pytest test_markers.py -v -m stress
```

you get the following output:

```
collected 3 items

test_markers.py::test_stress PASSED
```

If you want to execute the "stress" tests and the unmarked tests use:

```
pytest test_markers.py -v -m "not myplatform"
```

which gives you that output:

```
collected 3 items

test_markers.py::test_stress PASSED
test_markers.py::test_unmarked PASSED
```